# Algebraic curves: basic question on the Petri multiplication map $\mu_0$

Tags: algebraic-geometry, algebraic-curves

I am reading Arbarello et al. "Geometry of algebraic curves" where, given a curve $C$ and a line bundle $A$ on $C$, the map
$$\mu_0(A)\colon H^0(A)\otimes H^0(K_C-A)\to H^0(K_C)$$
is defined by the multiplication of sections. My question is really basic: if $\Delta$ is the divisor of base-points of $A$, then the following implication:
$$\ker\mu_0(A)\neq0 \Rightarrow \ker\mu_0(A-\Delta)\neq0 $$
appears to be obvious, but I am unable to prove it and get a bit confused.

How can one see this?

Comment: Did you carefully use the fact that $H^0(A)=H^0(A-\Delta)$?

Comment: @Mohan. Oh, right. But then what should we say about $H^0(K_C-A+\Delta)$? In the first place I thought that each  $t\in H^0(K_C-A+\Delta)$ can be written as $u\cdot v$ with $v=0$ on $\Delta$ but I think it's wrong: $\Delta$ will not be in the base locus for  $K_C-A+\Delta$, correct?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since $H^0(A)=H^0(A-\Delta)$, letting $i:H^0(K-\Delta)\to H^0(K)$ be the natural inclusion and $\nu:H^0(A-\Delta)\otimes H^0(K-A)\to H^0(K-\Delta)$, we have $\mu_0(A)=i\circ\nu$, not injective. We also have the natural inclusion $j:H^0(A-\Delta)\otimes H^0(K-A)\to H^0(A-\Delta)\otimes H^0(K-A+\Delta)$ and then $\mu_0(A-\Delta)\circ j=i\circ \nu$. Since the latter is not injective and $j$ is injective, we get that $\mu_0(A-\Delta)$ is not injective.